# uint8 displays weird characters

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I've declared a uint8 variable and when the value in it is printed, I get smiley faces and white spaces. Shouldn't it display integer values?

Comment: I'm using a library from a vendor..it returns a uint8 type

Comment: Are you trying to print it as a string using the `%s` format specifier? Try to print out the individual characters instead.

Comment: I'm reading it into a stringstream and printing .str()

Answer (score 17):

I bet `uint8` is a `typedef` for `unsigned char` in your system headers. Then `std::cout << u` will print symbols rather than integer values, where `u` is of type `uint8`.
Try

```
std::cout << static_cast< int >( u );
```

or

```
std::cout << +u;
```

to have numeric values printed.

Comment: Yes, it will. But what's the problem? That creates a temporary int from your uint8 variable and feeds that int to std::cout for printing.

Comment: @Rajesh. If you are printing in decimal do you think it makes any difference if the value is stored in a uint8 or a uint32 just before it is printed?

Comment: @usta: +1 for the nice little trick with the `+u`  for the auto conversion to int.

Comment: I'm actually not printing directly, I'm reading it into a stringstream and then printing .str()

Comment: The same answer still applies. Instead of std::cout, you'll have some 'os' object of type std::stringstream

Comment: if someone is trying to return uint8 types and pass them as an int, beware that the compiler will take this value as a character.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how you printing the value out. For cout, try `cout << (long unsigned int)var;`, and for `printf`, you can try using the `%lu` format specifier. However, like usta mentioned, `uint8` is likely defined or typedef'd as something else, since that is not an ISO C++ type. There is also the possibility that `uint8` is typedef'd to `unsigned long int` (generic), or `unsigned __int64` (MS platform specific), and the MSVC++ compiler is just doing the wrong implicit conversion. Without knowing what `uint8` is defined as, it is hard to tell.

Comment: uint8 is being used directly.... > typedef uint8 _UINT1; In the comment, it says 1 byte integer(How do i put a grey block around code?)

Comment: Well, then `_UIN1;` is likely defined as something else, too. You'd have to follow the typedef's until you hit the underlying intrinsic type (although, `_UINT1` seems to imply a single unsigned char, not a 64 bit number). Also, you can specify text as code (i.e. the "grey box") by wrapping it in back quote characters.

Comment: typedef uint8 _UINT1; defines _UINT1 as alias to uint8, not the other way around. So you'll have to look for a typedef XXX uint8; declaration to find out what uint8 is. Or you can just trust me that it is an 8-bit unsigned integer, and is an alias for unsigned char :)
[u]intN[_t] types always signify N-bit integers, not N-byte integers.

Comment: Yep, my bad... I read it like it was a `#define` for some reason ::duh::. It also seems (like usta says), the 8 is referring to the number of bits in the number, not the number of bytes.